# How to get Django-Q to send a message once the broker has finished executing a task?

Tags: django, asynchronous, redis

I have a django app that needs to send some big tasks to the backend to execute aysnchronously.  I'm using django-q with redis for this.

It works at a basic level - the task is sent to redis, django is no longer blocked waiting - but it does it silently. The app doesn't know when the task is complete, or if it has completed successfully.  This makes it really brittle. I'm now trying to get a signal back from redis when the task is complete (successfully or not).

Looking at the DjangoQ [documentation](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tasks.html), I've set up the following proof of concept:

*views.py*

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django_q_tasks import async_task

def testredisview(request):
    json_payload = {"message": "hello world!"}
    async_task("services.sleep_and_print", 10, hook='hooks.print_result')
    return JsonResponse(json_payload)
```

*services.py*

```
from time import sleep

def sleep_and_print(secs):
    sleep(secs)
    print("task done")
```

*hooks.py*

```
def print_result(task):
    print((task.id, task.result))
```

When I run `python3 manage.py qcluster` and then hit the url `127.0.0.1:8000/testredis`, 10 seconds later I get the JSON: `message: "hello world!"`  and the django server shows: `[Q] INFO Enqueued 1`, so it's executing the service command successfully.

However, the cluster shows:

```
[Q] INFO Q Cluster -cluster_name- running.
[Q] INFO Process-1:1 processing [-process_name-]
'task done'
'(-task_id-, None)'
[Q] INFO Processed [-process_name-]
```

The documentation states that `task.result = None` means that task hasn't been executed, and that `hook` is called after the task has been executed, so I would have expected a result object to be returned, instead of `None`

I've tried enforcing synchronicity (`Q_CLUSTER['sync']=True`) but have the same results.

Comment: You are not returning anything from your function, why would you expect to get anything other than None

Comment: Yeah.  That's a pretty obvious fix now that you point it out!  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obvious that your task has been run as it prints out text, also your hook runs after task is finished

You are getting result None as you are not returning any result from your method

example:

```
def sleep_and_print(secs):
    sleep(secs)
    print("task done")
    return True
```